# Theorem 3.7 in Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The set of all subsequential limits of a sequence $(p_n)$ in a metric space $X$ is closed.

Let $E:=\{p\in X: \text{ $p$ is a limit of a subsequence of $(p_n)$ }\}$. It is to be shown that $E$ is closed.

If $E$ is finite or equal to $X$, then there is nothing to prove. So suppose that $E$ is infinite and that $E\ne X$. Let $y\in E^c$.

$y$ is not a subsequential limit of $( p_n)$, i.e., there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $B(y,\delta)\setminus \{y\}$ contains no element of the sequence $(p_n)$ .

The following proves the claim that $B(y,\delta)$ contains no subsequential limit of $(p_n)$.

Suppose on the contrary that $z\in B(y,\delta)$ is a subsequential limit of $(p_n)$. This means that there is an $\epsilon\in (0,\min(d(z,y),\delta-d(z,y))$ such that $B(z,\epsilon)$ contains an element from the sequence $(p_n)$, which contradicts the fact that $B(y,\delta)\setminus \{y\}$ contains no element of the sequence $(p_n)$.

It follows that $B(y,\delta)\in E^c$. This means that $y$ is an interior point of $E^c$. Since $y$ was chosen arbitrarily, it follows that $E^c$ is an open set in $X$. Therefore, $E$ must be closed in $X$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: Your point about $z$ being a subsequential limit is not quite right as you say "This means" instead of "This implies". Even then, $z$ could be an isolated point and no such $\epsilon$ would exist. So it's safer using the precise definition with the universal quantifier, something along the lines "for each $ \epsilon > 0$, $B(z, \epsilon )$ contains...". But aside from that, I think it's alright.

Comment: I think a direct proof is not too difficult to obtained. Suppose $y\in \overline{X}$ where $X$ is the collection of all sub sequential limits of $(p_n)$. For each $k$, let $y_k\in X$ such that $d(y_k,y)<\frac1k$.
Since each $y_k$ is a sub sequential limit, there are $n_k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n_k<n_{k+1}$ such that $d(y_k,p_{n_k})<\frac{1}{k}$. Then
$$d(y,p_{n_k})\leq d(y,y_k)+d(y_k,p_{n_k})<\frac2k$$
This shows that $y$ is a sub sequential limit (the subsequence $k\mapsto p_{n_k}$ converges to $y$).

Comment: @LázaroAlbuquerque: Noted. Thanks a lot for the comment :).

Comment: @OliverDíaz: Thanks a lot for the comment. That's how I also tried but then I got confused using the subscripts. For example: How should I denote a sequence that converges to $y_k$. But I have realized that there is no need to use that fact.  Using the fact that there are $p_{n_k}$'s is enough. :)

Comment: I would second @OliverDíaz's remark.